# Ruby Cucumber env.rb refactor

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have this env.rb file created with a lot of information in it. I like to refactor it to be more readable. Maybe extract some of the code into a separate file or move some of the code to its own class or module file. But I am not sure how to do that.

1. env.rb

   ```
   require 'page-object'
   require 'page-object/page_factory'
   require 'active_record'

   World(PageObject::PageFactory)

   current_directory = File.dirname __FILE__

   web_config_file = current_directory + '/../../config/config.yml'
   web_config = YAML.load_file web_config_file

   BASE_URL = web_config['testApplicationBaseURL']
   browser =  Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

   # Creating two cookies to the browser to avoid a dialog to appear
   browser.navigate.to(BASE_URL)

   visited_before_cookie = {
             :name => 'visitedBefore',
             :value => 'yes',
             :path => '/',
             :domain => 'xxxx.net',
             :secure => false
   }

   saw_browser_suggestion_cookie = {
             :name => 'sawBrowserSuggestion',
             :value => 'yes',
             :path => '/',
             :domain => 'xxxx.net',
             :secure => false
   }

   browser.manage.add_cookie(visited_before_cookie)
   browser.manage.add_cookie(saw_browser_suggestion_cookie)

   #hooks
   Before do
     @browser = browser
   end

   at_exit do
     browser.close
   end
   ```
2. I tried to move the cookie creation piece below to a separate file, but  "browser" variable became undefined. I don't know how to scope it.

   ```
   browser =  Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

   # Creating two cookies to the browser to avoid a dialog to appear
   browser.navigate.to(BASE_URL)

   visited_before_cookie = {
             :name => 'visitedBefore',
             :value => 'yes',
             :path => '/',
             :domain => 'xxxx.net',
             :secure => false
   }

   saw_browser_suggestion_cookie = {
             :name => 'sawBrowserSuggestion',
             :value => 'yes',
             :path => '/',
             :domain => 'xxxx.net',
             :secure => false
   }

   browser.manage.add_cookie(visited_before_cookie)
   browser.manage.add_cookie(saw_browser_suggestion_cookie)
   ```
3. I thought about moving the hooks to hooks.rb file, but then local variable browser will not be set with those cookies that need to be created.

   ```
   #hooks
   Before do
     @browser = browser
   end

   at_exit do
     browser.close
   end
   ```
4. How would you do it? Would you use a file or class or module? Please share your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `browser` initially defined in a top-level block the way you would in `env.rb`, then you need to pass it in as an argument to code that's defined in other files (i.e. run from other scripts).

So you can, for example (and not necessarily a great example), create a module like

```
module BrowserConfigurator

  visited_before_cookie = {
      :name => 'visitedBefore',
      :value => 'yes',
      :path => '/',
      :domain => 'xxxx.net',
      :secure => false
  }

  saw_browser_suggestion_cookie = {
          :name => 'sawBrowserSuggestion',
          :value => 'yes',
          :path => '/',
          :domain => 'xxxx.net',
          :secure => false
  }

  def self.create_required_cookies(browser)
    browser.manage.add_cookie(visited_before_cookie)
    browser.manage.add_cookie(saw_browser_suggestion_cookie)
  end
end
```

and then inside `env.rb`, call

```
BrowserConfigurator.create_required_cookies(browser)
```

(disclaimer: I typed this code here without testing it so it might need tweaking)

Also, the two hooks you wanted to move to `hooks.rb` cannot be moved precisely because of scoping. Other hooks, on the other hand, can typically be put into a separate file.

Comment: I put  "require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)+'/helpers/browser_configurator')" in file env.rb; made cookie variable instance variables. It works! Thank you Dmitry!